# C libraries using QT

Tags: c, linux, qt

I need to use functions from capability.h library inside my QT project. So I've successfully included <sys/capability.h> in my cpp file and tried this:

```
char *result = NULL;
ssize_t length;
cap_t caps;
path = "/*path/*";

caps = cap_get_file(path);
if (caps)
   result = cap_to_text(caps, &length);
else
   qDebug() << "ERROR";

cap_free(caps);
```

Now I have problems like "undefined reference to `cap_get_file`" with cap_get_file, cap_to_text and cap_free functions. What am I doing wrong and how should I use linux system libraries in QT?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu and libcap (capabilities) undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338379/ubuntu-and-libcap-capabilities-undefined-reference)

Comment: @SparKot, yeah, that must be the problem. But I still don't quite understand how to specify -lcap using QtCreator

Comment: [qtcreator - Adding Libraries to Projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) didn't help?

Comment: "LIBS += -lcap" helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your `.pro` file:

```
LIBS += -lcap
```

It should do the trick.